# Convert JPG to TIFF using ghost script

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

i am trying to convert images from .jpg to .tiff using ghost script.And i have executed following command to do that.

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=tiffg3 -sOutputFile=sip.tiff -f sipchat.jpg
```

But i am getting this errors.

```
Error: /undefined in �����Exif
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1894   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   1771   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1155/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 11
GPL Ghostscript 9.04: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

What is the problem with my command? Any suggestion and guidance will be appreciated.I have to convert my images using ghost script because if i am using the images which is converted by other tools is not being accepted.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use ImageMagick...?

```
convert rose.jpg rose.tiff
```

Answer (score 1):

Old thing, but anyway.

I am looking for a way to convert JPG to TIFF for Tesseract, and stumbled into this.

Can't help myself, but why are You asking "why don't you just use imagemagick"?

AFAIK, imagemagick uses gs somewhere down there...but anyway the question was about ghostscript, not ImageMagick.